# how can I achieve this hover effect? Tried several methods with no luck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey guys how can I achieve a hover effect like the one used on the site below?

http:// minimalmonkey .com/

My current HTML:
http://pastebin.com/jCiy0ghX

And my CSS:
http://pastebin.com/WeQBDx8b

Tried lots of different methods such as borders on hover & width change on hover but didn't have any luck..

Thanks in advance, Luke.

Comment: create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4v3GE/1/

Comment: include your javascript attempts too? Seeing as it's the JS that you need help with

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it similar, there is couple of things to have in mind according to details:

1. when it grows content don't move from position - that's why
   padding is affected
2. Column tends to growing around its center - margin and border altered at the same time to accomplish that.
3. Outer columns seems to fade into background - opacity changes because of that for them.

Apart from creating a container to wrap columns, everything is plain CSS

modified CSS:

```
/* Column Styling CSS */

#left-column{
  background-color: #27ae60;
  left:0;
    border-color:#27ae60;    
}

#centre-column{
  background-color: #e67e22;
  left: 33.33%;
    border-color:#e67e22;
}

#right-column{
  background-color: #c0392b;
  left: 66.66%;
    border-color:#c0392b;
}

div[id$="column"]{
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100%;
    position: absolute;     
}

.columns{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.columns:hover div{
    /*
        transition for animation in modern browsers
    */    
    transition: opacity linear .2s;    
    opacity:0.3;
}

div[id$="column"]:hover{
    /*
        transition for animation in modern browsers
    */    
    transition: border ease-out .1s,margin ease-out .1s,padding ease-out .1s;
    z-index:200;
    margin-left:-20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    border-right:solid 20px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

I have used transition property w/out prefixes.  You should go for the one that works for you.  Check demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/pixshatterer/Zf6VU/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with just CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/4v3GE/5/

NOTE: I added a column container.

```
.column {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
            transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
}

.column--left{
    background-color: #27ae60;
}

.column--center {
    background-color: #e67e22;
}

.column--right {
    background-color: #c0392b;
}


/* Hover styling */

.columns:hover .column {
    width: 25%;
}

.columns .column:hover {
    width: 50%;
}
```